# Algorithms (millions of solid random intersections)

Tags: computational-geometry

I am looking for a numerical method to calculate the volume of the intersection of more than two cylinders in any angle (not just 90° (Steinmetz Solid)). There is an old Hubbell paper (1965) but it just work for two cylinders.

Evidently, I can make the calculation by hand, but I need a numerical method since I am making calculations for millions of random intersections.

Comment: For my understanding, are the axis converging to a single point and radii equal ?

Comment: "Evidently, I can make the calculation by hand": how so ? Even for two cylindres this is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Exact computation of the intersection volume looks like an endeavour. The graph of edges can have high complexity, and the edges are complicated skew curves.

I would try with a voxelization of space, one bit per voxel (2000³ voxels requiring 1GB of memory). Maybe an octree representation can help lower the storage requirement, with the number of cells required being closer to the area than to the volume.

Anyway, the filling of the cyclindres will take a quite significant amount of time.